# How to make input type text auto-expand also set specific width expand.

Tags: css, alignment, css-position

I have a search field which doesn't align like i want to
Here is the code

```
#menu_search{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1280px;
    display: inline; 
    float: right;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

So i want the search to be in the right part of the screen but only for max 1280 px, otherwise to maintain the alignment to 1280px (center of screen)

--------------------------------1480px-----------------------------

XXXXXX----------------------1280px----------[search]XXXXXX

Comment: See my answer here regarding flex and flex-grow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52975265/1599699

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### check your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NkfBu/2/)

#### HTML

```
 <input id="menu_search" type="text" size="20" placeholder="search here..." />
```

#### CSS

```
#menu_search{
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 1280px;
    display: inline; 
    float: right;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

#### j-Query (library 1.7.2)

```
$(function(){ 
    $('#menu_search').keyup(function(){ 
        var size = parseInt($(this).attr('size')); 
        var chars = $(this).val().length; 
        if(chars >= size) $(this).attr('size', chars); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: $('#keywords').on('keydown', function(e) {
      var minSize = 20;
      var maxSize = 50;
      var chars = $(this).val().length;
      $(this).attr('size', Math.min(Math.max(chars, minSize), maxSize));
    })

Answer (score -1):

You can use the CSS3 `media queries` to adjust the position of the `search field` according to the resolution of the screen.

You can read more about them at this [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Now for the question you asked the CSS only solution will be something like this.

```
@media screen and(max-width: 1280px) {
    #menu_search {
        position: absolute;
        display: inline;
        align: right;
        right: 0px;
        z-index: 99;
    }
}

@media screen and(min-width: 1281px) {
    #menu_search {
        position: absolute;
        float: left;
        display: inline;
        clear: both;
        margin: 0px 40 % ;
        /*try adjusting this magin values to get it exactly in center coz its dependent on the size of your text field also*/
       broder: 1px solid black;
    }
}
```

You can check  this [JSfillde link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/c5kPk/4/) for a demo

PS: you might want to play around with the `margin`'s values to suit your needs.